# Odd permutations conjugated by an even permutation

Tags: group-theory, permutations

My question is a notational one.

Consider the $S_n$ group. Now, two **even** permutations $R$, $S$ in $S_n$ which are conjugate by an **even** permutation can be said to be conjugate in the $A_n$ group. We can also express this fact by saying that $R$ lies in the $Cl_{A_n} (S)$ class.

What about two **odd** permutations $P, Q$ conjugated by an **even** permutation?

Am I right in assuming that it is meaningless to say that $P$ lies in the $Cl_{A_n} (Q)$ class (as $P, Q$ are not in the $A_n$ group)?

Is there any other standard way to express this fact?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Any odd permutation is, by definition, a product of an odd number of transpositions; any even permutation, an even number; and the inverse of any even permutation is even. Hence the conjugate of any odd permutation by any even permutation is odd.

Comment: This seems to answer a different question.

Comment: That's a fair observation, @AndreasBlass. Thank you. I had that impression as I was writing it up. I think verret's answer is superior to mine.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that $P$ and $Q$ are conjugate under $A_n$. This is a common expression, even if $P$ and $Q$ are not in $A_n$ themselves. If you really want to use "classes", you could say that they are in the same "class" or "orbit" of the action of $A_n$ on $S_n$ by conjugation, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly along the lines of what I had in mind.